# Magento: 500 Internal Server Error after upgrading to 2.4.4

Tags: magento2, upgrade, composer, cli, http-error-500

The store front shows `500 Internal server error` after I followed all instructions in the article [here](https://www.mgt-commerce.com/tutorial/how-to-upgrade-magento-2-4-3-to-magento-2-4-4/) to upgrade Magento. On checking the version of Magento with the command `bin/magento --version` after the upgrade process, I see this old version.

[image]

[image]

Running git status shows what's seen in the image below.

I'm not sure if Magento upgrade went fine. Could you please help me fix 500 Internal Server error?

Comment: You need to enable PHP error log and see real (fatal) error, without this information doesn't make sense to guess about the reason.

Comment: Hi there , if 500 error comes , please get the preview or response from the network tab in chrome dev tools and post it here , so we can help you out more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix 500 errors in Magento 2, there could be multiple reasons:

- Permission Issue
- Memory Limitation Issue
- Version compatibility issue
- Third-party extension issue
- htaccess Issue

And more,

First, please enable the PHP error log and also the server log to check what actually the problem is.

you can still figure it out:
please check the full documentation: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/magento-500-error/

For the upgrade please pull your code and check the composer json if it's updated with the current latest version so that the composer can upgrade the dependencies.

Thanks